# css displaying 404 on a github pages site

Tags: css, github, http-status-code-404, github-pages

So my index.html is showing up fine, but the css isn't working. I opened the developer tools in Chrome, and all the CSS files had a 404 error. I believe the issue is on the Github side??

I switched repositories for this new Github page, and was working before.

Here is the repository:
https://github.com/Samtrapskin/samtrapskin.github.io

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: did you change the index.html place ? or your importing the css from template folder?

Comment: you have not copyed the main.css and the common.css to the asset folder. If you set the url from "assets/css/main.css" to "main.css" it "works" and loads. But I don't no if this is right what it shows.

Comment: Thanks! I did fix the url for css and it worked. I didn't realize the url path was different. I had to adjust the url for the img folder as well.

Comment: ok  great because it was a path problem i changed the path it worked

Answer (score 0):

those two should be like this

link rel="stylesheet" href="common.css">

link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">

and here css should all have Template

link rel="stylesheet" href="Template/assets/libs/animate/animate.min.css">

and js too all should have Template

script src="Template/assets/js/components.js">

i hope this will help